# flink kubernetes operator 1.4.0 autoscaler

Tags: apache-flink

I have the below deployment.

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  image: raniantouni/flink117
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.enabled: "true"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.scaling.sources.enabled: "false"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.scaling.enabled: "true"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.stabilization.interval: "1m"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.metrics.window: "3m"
    kubernetes.operator.metrics.reporter.slf4j.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.slf4j.Slf4jReporterFactory
    metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
    pipeline.max-parallelism: "24"
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "4"
    state.savepoints.dir: file:///flink-data/savepoints
    state.checkpoints.dir: file:///flink-data/checkpoints
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.storageDir: file:///flink-data/ha
    execution.checkpointing.interval: "1m"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 0.5
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
```

I have disabled the source scaling operation. I see this error in operator's logs

```
2023-05-22 14:54:25,494 o.a.f.k.o.a.m.ScalingMetrics   [ERROR][default/example] Cannot compute true processing/output rate without busyTimeMsPerSecond
```

I don't know the reason why the operator has no access to this. Has anyone any idea ? Do I have to add more configurations?